# dynamically build code and use in .write() python

Tags: python

I want to covert a large tab separated .txt file into a csv, but make it reusable with any file with any number of columns. I attempted using the csv module's normal processes, but want to do it one line at a time to keep memory usage minimal.

The below code is my attempt, but after looking for hours cannot find an effective way to insert the correct text into the outFile.write().  Is there a sort of reverse repr that will insert the .format and strings to work properly?

Thanks!

```
import csv

openFile = open("tsvTest.txt")
outFile = open("csvTest.csv", "w")
c = 0
for line in openFile:
    tString = line.split('\t')
    if c == 0:
        x = 0
        lString = []
        length = len(tString)
        while x < length-1:
            lString.append("{{tString["+str(x)+"]}}")
            x = x+1
        #lineInput = ''.join(map(str, lString))
        c = 1

    outFile.write(lString)
outFile.close()
```

Comment: No pandas please. This is for others to use with only base library

Comment: `lString.extend(tString)`, then `lineInput = ','.join(lString)`

Comment: Did you notice that you aren't actually using any functions from the `csv` module? And this code, `"{{tString["+str(x)+"]}}"`, doesn't produce anything resembling CSV. Care to enlighten us as to what you're really trying to do with the sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have no tabs in the fields itself (since you use split('\t')), you could do:

```
with open("tsvTest.txt") as I, open("csvTest.csv", "w") as O:
    for line in I:
        flds = line.split('\t')
        O.write(','.join(flds))
```

Comment: what about `line.replace('\t', ',')` ?

Comment: @joaquin : I used the split because it is in the example, but replace will do the job too and the join can be skipped

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: This solution is not safe. If the input contains commas incorrect output will occur. You should only use a simplistic solution like this if you can guarantee the input will not contain commas or escaped tabs that do not delimit fields.